# Count the total number of subsets such that $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{3} T_{i} = P$

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set $P = \{1,2,3\}$. We define another set $S = P \times P \times P$. Count the number of tuples $(T_1,T_2,T_3)$, where $T_i$ is a subset of the set $P$, such that $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{3} T_{i} = P$.

My approach - My guess is that I have to apply principle of inclusion and exclusion here. If I count the total number of such tuples that can be formed using the set and then remove the unwanted cases, like the subsets that don't contain a single element from the set $P$, then I'll get the answer. However, I'm having trouble counting the number of tuples in each case.

Is my approach correct? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Correct "$T_i$ is a subset of $S$" to "$T_i$ is a subset of $P$".

Comment: @kabenyuk Hi, $T_i$ is a subset of the set $S$

Comment: In that case, the problem looks pretty meaningless. There are no such triples. Maybe $\cup T_i=S$? Also, what is $k$ in this formula?

Comment: Yeah I corrected the question, the $k$ in the question was not required.

Comment: How can T_i lie in P and S at the same time?

Comment: Assuming you mean $T_i$ is a subset of $P$... so $(T_1,T_2,T_3)$ is an element of $S$... For each element $k$ of $P$... choose which subset of $T_1,T_2,T_3$ that $k$ will appear in each of... noting that it must have appeared in at least one of them to appear in the end after taking the union of these.

Comment: So... as an example... $(\{1\},\{2,3\},\{1,3\})$ is a triple of *subsets of $P$* and we have $\{1\}\cup \{2,3\}\cup \{1,3\}=\{1,2,3\}=P$.  Similarly $(\emptyset,\{1,2,3\},\{1\})$ we have $\emptyset\cup \{1,2,3\}\cup \{1\}=\{1,2,3\}$.  Having the $T_i$ be elements of $S$ does not make sense, as already pointed out... that would look something like an example of $(T_1,T_2,T_3)$ would be something like $((\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}),(\{2\},\{1\},\emptyset),(\{3\},\{1,2\},\{3\}))$... a triple *of triples* of subsets of $P$...  Having $T_i$ be *subsets of $S$* is even more bizarre looking.

Comment: Right, understood. I interpreted the question the wrong way.  Thanks!

Comment: So... again, you *could* do inclusion-exclusion if you really insisted... but it will be tedious.  In the case that $P=\{1,2,3,4,\dots,n\}$ instead... you'd have an answer of something along the lines of $n^3-\binom{n}{1}(2^{n-1})^3+\binom{n}{2}(2^{n-2})^3-\binom{n}{3}(2^{n-3})^3+\dots\pm \binom{n}{k}(2^{n-k})^3\pm\dots\pm \binom{n}{n}(2^{0})^3$.  Using my hint above you can get an immediate answer that can be written with only two or three characters.

Comment: It does yield at least a [satisfying identity](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D0+to+n+of+%28%28-1%29%5Ek*%28n+choose+k%29*%282%5E%28n-k%29%29%5E3%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to consider which sets the elements of $P$ lie in. There are $3$ elements in $P$. For $\cup_{i=1}^3 T_i=P$, we require that each element $k\in P$ is in at least one of $T_i$.

Each $T_i$ has $2$ choices: contain $k$ or do not contain $k$. This gives $2^3$ possibilities. However, we cannot have that all $T_i$ choose to not contain $k$, hence there are $\boxed{2^3-1}$ possibilities for each $k\in P$.

Since there are $3$ different values of $k$ that we need to consider, and each of these $k\in P$ have $2^3-1$ ways to be placed in the sets $T_i$, there are $\boxed{\left(2^3-1\right)^3=343}$ ordered triples $(T_1,T_2,T_3)$

---

For fun, let's generalize the problem so that $|P|=n$ and we want to find the number of ordered $k$-tuples $(T_1,T_2,\ldots T_k)$.

Using the same reasoning, for any element $e\in P$, we have $2^k-1$ ways for it to appear in the $k$-tuple $(T_1,T_2,\ldots T_k)$ so that it appears at least once.

Since we have to account for each of these $n$ elements, the total number of ordered $k$-tuples is $\left(2^k-1\right)^n$. In your problem, we have $n,k=3$, which yields $\left(2^3-1\right)^3=\boxed{343}$